# What's the default font family?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This returns `null`:

```
DefaultFontFamily = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Default).FontFamily;
```

As well as this:

```
DefaultFontFamily = new Label().FontFamily;
```

What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no right way to do it - as there is no cross-platform 'default font family' to pull up here and, also the fact that it is platform specific.

To elaborate on this further, would like to refer this property as defined in source code for [`Label`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Label.cs#L30),

```
public static readonly BindableProperty FontFamilyProperty = FontElement.FontFamilyProperty;
```

which in turn refers to the dependency property as defined in [`FontElement`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FontElement.cs#L11),

```
public static readonly BindableProperty FontFamilyProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("FontFamily", typeof(string), typeof(IFontElement), default(string),
                                propertyChanged: OnFontFamilyChanged);
```

or the static method you referred for [`SystemFontOfSize`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Font.cs#L67).

```
public static Font SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize size)
{
    var result = new Font { NamedSize = size };
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, in both cases, as per source code, the value `'null'` for `FontFamily` is not unexpected. (In first case, the dependency property is defined with default value as `default(string)` which translates to null, and in second case, value for `FontFamily` is never set)

Same goes for [`Font.Default`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Font.cs#L26). On further digging, you come across [`IsDefault`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Font.cs#L16) which is defined as following:

```
public bool IsDefault
{
    get { return FontFamily == null && FontSize == 0 && NamedSize == NamedSize.Default && FontAttributes == FontAttributes.None; }
}
```

***So if `FontFamily` is `null`, then it is the default*** in xamarin forms eco-system.

---

When `Label` does get rendered on a particular platform, then unless its `FontFamily` property is specifically modified from `'null'` to some value, the font property on the native control is never modified either. So the native control is rendered with default font family for that platform.

In order to get that default font you will have to [implement native-services, and use dependency-injection](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/09/01/native-services-with-xamarinforms.aspx) to get that value.

For more details on native controls used for `Label` - you can refer this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers/#Views).