# Xamarin.Forms: Is there any way to set default Font (Family) in derived style in xaml?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, styles, cross-platform

I need to set (reset) font style to default in some Labels (for instance) when the basic Label style is setup to some specific font family.
I.e.:

```
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ThinFontFamily}" />
        </Style>


        <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="MyCustomStyle">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="... to some default"></Setter>
        </Style>
```

There are of course, two other ways: to define all the labels explicitly and use custom renderers, but this is like lots of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the default font family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088536/whats-the-default-font-family)

Comment: Not quite. I am asking (among others) about having it in xaml.

Comment: Create class CustomLabel. It should have your custom font and default Label have default font. Or vice versa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The platform default font family can be set with an empty value in the style setter property:

```
<Style x:Key="defaultLabel" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="" />
</Style>
...
<Label x:Name="label" Style="{StaticResource defaultLabel}"
       Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference label}, 
                      Path=Font, StringFormat='Default: {0}'}}" />
```